# Adding Text View to Image on iPhone X "squeezes" image on output

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I currently having a block of code that is trying to add a text view on top of an image, with the ultimate goal to save down the new image with the overlaid text. Here is the code to do that:

```
class func addText(label: UITextView,imageSize: CGSize, image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height), false, scale)
    let currentView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height))
    let currentImage = UIImageView.init(image: image)
    currentImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height)
    currentView.addSubview(currentImage)
    currentView.addSubview(label)
    currentView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return img!
}
```

And it is called like below (The image is just a standard 1920x1080 image taken by the phone's camera):

```
self.imageToEdit.image = UIImage.addText(label: textView, imageSize: UIScreen.main.bounds.size, image: self.imageToEdit.image!)
```

This works great when I test when an iPhone 6s, but when I test on an iPhone X, it "squeezes" the sides of the image so faces and other features become skinnier on the image that is returned by `addText`.

I have a hunch it is due to the image being extended up through the notch of the iPhone X which is causing some type of scaling/aspect fill, but I'm not sure where to begin looking.

Does anyone know how to stop the "squeezing" from happening in iPhone X (I am also guessing this is happening in all the other iPhone models that have a notch)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out!

I needed to included this line:

`currentImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill`

in my `addText` func.

Because I was returning a new `UIImageView` I needed to make sure it had the same content mode as the original view.